# Angular UI-Grid: filtering cross-column or cross-row

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm still learning about Angular/ui-grid and have gotten stuck and hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  When you set up your grid you can turn on filtering with:

```
$scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering = true;
```

Then in the *columnDefs* when you define your grid you can turn on column filtering with various tests (equal to, contains, exact, less than, etc. ) or make up your own - i.e.  you can even define your own boolean function to drive the pass/fail of each row for your desired filtering logic. Here's a typical example:

```
{
   field: 'phone',
   filter: {
     condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
       var strippedValue = (cellValue + '').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
       return strippedValue.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0;
     }
},
```

But this filtering logic ability all seems to be specific to one column. So what if you have a filtering test that is cross-field (simple example: does field A = field B?) or possibly even cross-row (i.e. I actually have a case where I do complex test across **sets** of rows to determine which rows should be filtered in/out). **Is there a standard method for how to do this sort of more global filtering?**

I've gotten close to a solution by saving the include/exclude results of the calculation in a hidden column that is not actually displayed, but I cannot seem to get ui-grid to actually execute the filter function on the hidden column.  This raises a related question:  **how can you force the execution of a filtering operation (because I would like to trigger from a control that is not part of the grid)?**

I tried to put together a plunkr of the simpler case (does A = B ?):  http://plnkr.co/edit/a0BJZVOGGIyP4Q4hxVob?p=preview

I think if I understood how to make that work, perhaps the answer would also answer (or make moot) the dynamic aspect (how to force the filter operation when needed) of the problem as well.

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 2):

I've added a cross field example today to the tutorials: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/321_singleFilter

The key is that the base filtering works on a column at a time.  It starts with all the rows visible, and then sets a row invisible if it doesn't match any of the individual column filters.  What you're asking for is more akin to an OR condition, which the filtering doesn't currently support.

What you can do, though, is build a custom rowsProcessor that applies custom filtering, and the tutorial provides an example of that.

Comment: thanks for that info Paul - I did not know about rowsProcessors.  I gave it a try and I see that I can create any sort of global filter with this.  But I'm guessing that this precludes the use of the standard column-top filters?  the grid seems to freeze if I try to do both.

Comment: It shouldn't preclude using both, they should work independently of each other.

Comment: But I notice that in your 321-tutorial (thanks for that Paul), the critical line seems to be row.visible = true/false, as opposed to the 'condition' functions that simply return true/false and then the grid combines the values.  Does that logical combining really happen in this case?

Comment: No, this is entirely outside the standard filtering (which lives in rowSearcher.js), so it doesn't support conditions etc.  I think it would be possible to apply this approach to the core filtering, and therefore use all the different permutations of conditions, but I haven't tried to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
{
   field: 'phone',
   filter: {
     condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
       var strippedValue = (cellValue + '').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
       var match1 = strippedValue.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0;
       var match2 = // some Other condition
       return (match1 || match2); //add additional matches as needed.
     }
},
```

Comment: Thanks.  That could do it for me.  But is there a way to force (from outside the Grid controller) the re-evaluation of this column-top filter?  (the "other condition" is unrelated to the Grid data.